# I am getting an error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISBLANK()'

Tags: compile-error

[image]

I am getting a Syntax error for ISBLANK. I am trying to configure an automation that if I have a checked box on the customer page ("SandSafe" is the check box name) then when users create work orders it will populate that check box in the same field on the work order which, when the work order is moved to the completed status it will either

1. send an e-mail off with the completed work order so our GM's know that work order needs to be billed for (unchecked box)

or

2. no e-mail will be sent because the check box is checked and we will not need to bill back that work order.

Answer (score 2):

`ISBLANK` is for Strings - instead, you can directly check for `true` or `false` (`NOT` expects a boolean)

```
NOT([FX5_WorkOrder_c].SandSafe_Customer__c)
```

The whole thing could be written (you can leave `NOT` out):

```
ISCHANGED([FX5_WorkOrder_c].SandSafe_Customer__c ) &&
[FX5_WorkOrder_c].SandSafe_Customer__c = TRUE
```

Reference [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)